# When should one set variables to 0 in the predictor matrix for multiple imputation?

Tags: multiple-imputation

**Background.** I am using multiple imputation using the "mice" package in R (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/mice.pdf) to handle missing data in a large public dataset I am analyzing. I have been following this tutorial, which has been incredibly helpful: https://library.virginia.edu/data/articles/getting-started-with-multiple-imputation-in-r. The tutorial raised a question for me, though. In the "Preprocessing Data" section of the tutorial I linked, there are a few variables that are set to 0 in the predictor matrix when customizing the multiple imputation methods and predictor matrix (under the comment, `# Setting values of variables I'd like to leave out to 0 in the predictor matrix`). Reading further in the tutorial, it seems like the variables set to 0 in the predictor matrix are mostly those where there is no missing data. However, it also seems possible that variables would be excluded because they are not meaningful (such as random IDs), are redundant to or highly correlated with another variable in the dataset, or are not relevant to the question at hand.

**Question.** I was wondering when, in general, variables should be set to 0 in the predictor matrix used in multiple imputation as they are in the tutorial linked above, and why?

Thanks for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: I found an answer to my own question in this textbook (van Buuren, 2018): https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/ch-practice.html. The author clearly outlines how to customize prediction for MICE based on the specific idiosyncrasies of one's data.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a more detailed answer here. Link-only answers are generally considered low quality at CV and may be prone to removal by mods. Explaining the answer in some detail will help others more who come across this question.